# (0,0) in AndEngine is not correct

Tags: coordinates, sprite, andengine

i'm using AndEngine framwork for test but i draw my sprite in (0,0) but it draw in bottom right :| why?

this is my code:

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
                                    new FillResolutionPolicy(), camera);
    options.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);
    options.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);
    return options;
}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    ....
    head = new Sprite(0, 0, head_region, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

Comment: it's amasing when i set (10,10) my head move to bottom left and when i set to (0,0) it's move to bottom right :|

Comment: I suspect, that you hold your device wrong? Try to use ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR and maybe your device will show the point correct. Another thing is, you should use the branch anchor-center, where all coordinates are centered.

Comment: In OpenGLES 2.0 it takes from bottom not from top. If you want from top use older version OpenGLES 1.0 of andengine but this will not be supported on many of the latest devices with advance features. Its better to start working with OpenGLES 2.0 n above.